# How to create a training set for regression in Python if in a dataset some individuals are represented by more samples than others?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am working on a regression problem and my dataset is very imbalanced. My features are age, sex, weight, medication dose, some lab results and I am trying to predict one column of continuous values.

In my dataset some individuals are represented by more samples than others. For example 30 lines of data from one individual, 10 from a second individual and 1 from a third and so on. I do not know how to select the training set so that the model is not biased towards specific subjects.

I divided the training and testing set in a way that there is no data from the same individuals in both sets but still training a model with a training set that is not balanced regarding the amount of data from each individual would bias the model.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to duplicate samples. So that, for example, every individual will have 30 rows of data.

As an alternative, you can also adjust the weights. So that an individual with 30 samples will have weight 1, an individual with 10 samples will have weight 3, and an individual with 30 samples will have weight 30 [it's an equivalent to duplicating, but doesn't increases the training set]

Comment: The individuals that have 30 rows of data, their data in each row is different except for their age and sex. Are you suggesting that I duplicate the data from an individual that has one row of data to create 30 rows and all of them include the same values?

Comment: However since adding sample weights yields the same result, it's probably more straight-forward to use them directly. To do so, note that `sklearn` models usually have the parameter `sample_weight` that allows this (as you can see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) for example). The sample weight should be 1/N, where N is the amount of rows for the individual in question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure how to duplicate an individuals data with 26 rows to reach 30 rows. Does it matter which row to duplicate? Is it okay to only duplicate the first row data of each individual?

Comment: However, if there is some correlation between one of the features and and number of samples (for example, if most of the poorly represented individuals are males) this approach will lead you to another problem.

Comment: In order to duplicate "data with 26 rows to reach 30 rows" you should take all the existing 26 rows, and add 4 randomly chosen from these 30.

Comment: "Is it okay to only duplicate the first row data of each individual?" --No

Comment: I will check to see if there is such a correlation but if there is, any idea how to deal with this problem?